# Center a whole CSS grid with respect to the whole page

Tags: html, css, centering

I have two tables that I want to be centered in my webpage (link here: https://juancarlosortizr.github.io/sudoku/sudoku.html). The CSS code for the tables is:

But I've tried looking everywhere and all I find is how to center text *within* the cells with respect to the cell itself; not how to center (horizontally) the table as a whole. Is there a way?

```css
    .grid-container {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-color: #c8a2c8;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    } 

    .grid-container2 {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    background-color: #c8a2c8;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    
    <!-- header and navbar omitted here -->
    
    <!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- "side" omitted here -->
    
      <div class="main">
    
        <h2 id="sudoku">Sudoku Solver</h2>
            <p>Input a solvable sudoku, and it'll spit out a solution! If it's unsolvable, it'll let you know.

                You can leave empty squares empty, or fill them out with a zero or a dot.
            </p>

                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="x1" name="quantity" min="1" max="9"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="x2" name="quantity" min="1" max="9"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="x3" name="quantity" min="1" max="9"></div> <!-- etc... -->
                    <div class="grid-item"><input type="number" id="x81" name="quantity" min="1" max="9"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <p> <button onclick="solveSudoku()">Click when ready!</button> </p>

                <body> 
                    Here is the solution board. If it is full of dots, that means no solution exists! (Sadly, in the current version of the project, the algorithm doesn't detect whether or not the solution is unique).
                </body>
                <p>

                <body>    
                <div class="grid-container2">
                    <div class="grid-item"> <text id="board1"></text> </div>
                    <div class="grid-item"> <text id="board2"></text> </div>
                    <div class="grid-item"> <text id="board3"></text> </div> <!-- etc... -->


                    <div class="grid-item"> <text id="board81"></text> </div>
                </div>
            </body>

            </p>
      </div>
       
    </body>
```

The whole thing can be found at https://github.com/juancarlosortizr/juancarlosortizr.github.io/blob/master/sudoku/sudoku.html.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML

Comment: @BeerusDev ok! Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

Instead of display: inline-grid;
Keep it: **display: grid;**

And add
**width: fit-content;**
in both the containers

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
background-color: #c8a2c8;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: -moz-fit-content; /* For Mozilla firefox*/
width: -webkit-fit-content; /* For Google Chrome */
width: fit-content;
} 

.grid-container2 {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px 40px;
background-color: #c8a2c8;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: -moz-fit-content; /* For Mozilla firefox*/
width: -webkit-fit-content; /* For Google Chrome */
width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution, add these rules to your css

```css
.panelb {
    display: flex;
}

.grid-container {
    /* flex: 1; <-- remove this line */
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-color: #c8a2c8;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

A similar method can be used for the second table although I see in your HTML you may need to add a container div.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but the HTML looks the same after adding this change. If instead I do #grid-container then it breaks the whole thing.

Comment: Maybe it's the "<div class="row">" that's breaking my website? My whole HTML is inside a <div class="row"> defined as

    .row {  
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }